# Xcode 6.1.1 unresolved symbol within boost library

Tags: xcode, boost

I have a project using boost_date_time that successfully built under Xcode 6.1.  I now get an error message under 6.1.1:
"boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&) in main.o

I have correctly entered in the search path tab, /usr/local/lib for the library search path, and included in custom compiler option, the C++ compiler option -lboost_filesystem.

If I use a terminal window, I can successfully use make or ld to generate the executable using g++ compiler options -L/usr/local/lib and -lboost_filesystem.

I reinstalled boost 1.57.0 to make sure that the boost library was up to date.

Does anyone know how to set the right options in Xcode to fix this problem?